# What do you call the following phrases?

Tags: phrases

In the following examples:

> A boy with blue eyes and black tshirt stood in the corner.
>
> An old man who knew how to live a life the right way looked through the window.

What would you call these phrases?

> with blue eyes and black tshirt
>
> who knew how to live a life the right way

I understand they are part of the subject. What would you call them when you do a grammatical analyses?

Also is there a list of patterns to form phrases like these?

I can create lots of variations and all will start from the words 'with' or 'who'. I suspect there are more ways to create phrases like these.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are **adjective phrases**. An adjective phrase is a group of words that describe a noun or pronoun in a sentence. The adjective phrase can be placed before, or after, the noun or pronoun in the sentence.

http://examples.yourdictionary.com/adjective-phrase-examples.html

Answer (score 1):

The second one is an adjective clause, not an adjective phrase. The fact that it begins with *who* is a clear sign. It also contains a verb, which phrases do not.